# insert several equation in one frame in beamer

Tags: equations

i hope you are doing well. I am doing in latex a beamer presentation. in one frame I am including several equations, but they do not appear in the slide. 
here is my MWE.

```
    \documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation> {
\usetheme{Madrid}}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Methodology}
\begin{block}{Levinsohn dhe Petrin (2003)}


$$Y_{it}=A_{it}K_{it}L_{it}M_{it}$$\pause 
$$y_{it}= \beta_{0} + \beta_{l} l_{it} + \beta_{k} k_{it} +\omega_{it} + \epsilon_{it}$$\pause 
$$m_{it}=f(k_{it};\omega_{it})$$ \pause 
$$\omega_{it}=f(k_{it};m_{it})$$ \pause
$$ \hat{A}_{it}= \beta_{0}+ \hat{\omega}_{it}$$\pause
$$ \hat{A}_{it}= y_{it} - \beta{k}k_{it}- \hat{\beta}_{l}l_{it}$$\pause 
$$TFP=exp(\hat{A}_{it})$$


\end{block}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Can you please suggest any possible solution?

thank you

Comment: A few notes: (1) you should never use  `$$...$$` with LaTeX it does not comply to LaTeX configurations. In this case I'd just use the `gather*` env, though read the `beamer` manual on how to apply `\pause` to rows in `gather` and friends. (2) use `\exp` not `exp` which is the same as `e·x·p`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Converting to `gather*` works just fine out of the box and does not have the large spacing between items that `$$...$$` comes with (`$$...$$` should never be 
used in LaTeX)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation> {
\usetheme{Madrid}}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

% just if you are not using the nav bar
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Methodology}
\begin{block}{Levinsohn dhe Petrin (2003)}
\begin{gather*}
  \uncover<+->{Y_{it}=A_{it}K_{it}L_{it}M_{it}  \\}
  \uncover<+->{ y_{it}= \beta_{0} + \beta_{l} l_{it} + \beta_{k} k_{it}
    +\omega_{it} + \epsilon_{it} \\}
  \uncover<+->{ m_{it}=f(k_{it};\omega_{it})\\}
  \uncover<+->{
    \omega_{it}=f(k_{it};m_{it})\\}
  \uncover<+->{   \hat{A}_{it}= \beta_{0}+ \hat{\omega}_{it} \\}
  \uncover<+->{
    \hat{A}_{it}= y_{it} - \beta{k}k_{it}- \hat{\beta}_{l}l_{it}
    \\}
  \uncover<+->{
    TFP=exp(\hat{A}_{it})
  }
\end{gather*}


\end{block}


\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Yes, having to add `\uncover` is annoying, but as the beamer manual says, `amsmath` does some very tricky things behind the scenes so this is the only thing that works.

BTW to give your code a good formatting mark the code and press `{}` in the interface or hit Ctrl-k if you are on a desktop (not sure if the shortcut is different on a Mac)

Comment: thanks, it worked just fine..